# Traversing foreign key related tables in django templates

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

### View

```
categories = Category.objects.all()
t = loader.get_template('index.html')
v = Context({
    'categories': categories
})
return HttpResponse(t.render(v))
```

### Template

```
{% for category in categories %}
    <h1>{{ category.name }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

this works great. now im trying to print each company in that category.  the company table has a foreign key to the category table

ive tried

```
{% for company in category.company_set.all() %}
```

seems django doesn't like () in templates

There's a maze of information on the django site i keep getting lost between the .96, 1.0 and dev version. im running django version 1.0.2

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Just get rid of the parentheses:

```
{% for company in category.company_set.all %}
```

Here's the [appropriate documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#variables). You can call methods that take 0 parameters this way.

Comment: son of a... I was looking in the wrong place the past 36 hours. Thanks so much...

Comment: [Link to method calls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/language/#accessing-method-calls)