# Reverse foreign key to django-fts searchable model in template

Tags: django, sqlite, postgresql, django-templates, psycopg2

I have a pair of Django models with a foreign key, one of which is searchable with django-fts, say:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    ...
class Bar(fts.SearchableModel):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
```

When I have an instance of Foo, in view I can insert `print foo.bar_set.all()` and I see an array of results.  However if I try to use it in a view, in any of following ways:

```
{{foo.bar_set|pprint}}
{{foo.bar_set.all|ppring}}
{{foo.bar_set.count}}
{{foo.bar_set.all|length}}
{% for bar in foo.bar_set.all %} {{bar}} {% endfor %}
```

and literally *any* construct that I can think of behaves as if `foo` instance had no `bar_set` attribute.

Edit: I am sure that I have a `Foo` instance in the template, I tested following to work as expected:

```
{{foo|pprint}}
{{foo.id}} (and any other simple attributes of Foo)
```

I am sure there are related Bar objects, as I check that from view (`print foo.bar_set.all()`).  And if the QuerySet was empty, `{{foo.bar_set.all|pprint}}` would yield `[]`, not `''` (which it does on `{{foo.bar_set.all|pprint}}`, `{{foo.bar_set|pprint}}`, and any `{{foo.nonexistent_attribute|pprint}}`).

This behaviour started when I moved development from SQLite database to PostgreSQL, with psycopg2 driver, to use django-fts full text search.

I could not find any other answer, because googling this is very hard: "reverse relationship" or "reverse foreign key" is all littered with unrelated `django.core.urlresolvers.reverse` references, and I have no idea how to name "*_set" thing to Google.  A hint on how to google this one would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Marcin Kaszyński](http://www.blip.pl/dm/12892100)'s help off the SO I managed to trace the bug down to [django-fts](http://code.google.com/p/django-fts/) BaseManager.  Django-fts is a full-text search engine, that adds `.search(query)` method to manager of searchable classes, co I can write `Foo.objects.search("bar")`.  For *convenience*, it adds `__call__` method to the manager, which is inherited by `RelatedManager` (instance of which is the `bar_set`).

The template code, in `django.templates.Variable._resolve_lookup` method, sees that `bar_set` is callable (line 717), tries to call it with no arguments (line 722), and treats the variable as empty because arguments were required (lines 724-726).

[Removing the __call__ method from django-fts' BaseManager](http://github.com/ryszard/django-fts/commit/03cf1abcb9262b4b0b9dd3b57ac07f7d507ddd8f) helps.

Answer (score 0):

`{{ foo.bar_set.all }}` should definitely work. Are you sure you actually have an instance of Foo?

Comment: I have an instance of Foo ({{foo|pprint}} works, I double-checked that), and all simple attributes (like {{foo.id}}) work.  There is a relation and there are related Bar objects, which I test by running print foo.bar_set.all() from view before rendering the template.

Comment: I found this, this was interaction with django-fts (I know I didn't mention this in first version of question text, I didn't suspect that to be the cause).  See my answer for extended explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest attempting to pass foo.bar_set.all as a dictionary element in the view function before rendering the page to see if you get the same result.

Comment: Methods with no parameters are called by template language (which works with other methods as well, and if problem would be with a method call, {{foo.bar_set|pprint}} would render *something*).  This is documented at http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/templates/#variables and  described in first question related to this one at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014591/traversing-foreign-key-related-tables-in-django-templates

Comment: Yes, I already used that as a workaround until I can find a solution to the problem (that works as the ready result set is just another template argument).  I downvoted your answer because it was a misinformation (about not being able to call methods), but I see you edited it, so I take the downvote back.

Comment: thank you for that, I'm trying to figure out why that doesn't work for you, myself. Truth is I've never gotten .object_set.all to work in the template. Same problem.

Comment: Are you sure that foo is not being passed from bar. For example, are you sure that foo is coming from: foo = Foo.objects.get() vs the foo that is in your bar model? That could cause the problem.

Comment: No, that is not the cause.  I found the cause, after I work out the code, I will post the full answer, as it is not obvious (it comes from django-fts actually, which was main reason to switch development to Postgres).