# How to display other entries of my filtered object in Django template

Tags: python, django, templates, object, filter

In my Django-Project I have a model, that looks like that:

```
class Tag_car(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car)
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag)
```

`car` is a foreign key of an ImageField and `tag` is a foreign key of a TextField.

Every car has more than only one tag.
Now users should be able to search for a specific car by a tag. I am doing it like that in my view:

```
…
search = request.POST.get('search')
cars = Tag_car.objects.filter(tag=search)
…
return render_to_response(page,context_instance=RequestContext(request, {'cars': cars}))
```

And in my Template I am displaying all cars then like that:

```
{% for car in cars %}
    <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ car.car }}">
{% endfor %}
```

It all works fine.
But now I also would like to display within the for-loop in the template all tags that are related to each car. When I do something like `{{ car.tag }}` I get obviously only the one tag for which the user was searching.
I am struggling how to pass all tags for each car to the view and then display them for each car.
Does anybody have an idea how to do that?
I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the issue is that the object you're passing to the template as `cars` is actually a list of `Tag_car` objects. So, in order to get the list of other tags related to each car, you need to follow the relationship to the car, then query the other tags:

```
{% for car in cars %}
    ...
    {% for tag in car.car.tag_set.all %}
        ...
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Note though that you should probably query Car objects in the first place, rather than Tag_cars. Plus, your Tag_car model is really just the through table of a many-to-many relationship, so rather than creating it explicitly you can just use a M2M field on the Car model:

```
tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

Comment: Also by using `car.car.tag_set.all` the for-loop is not being entered. I am concerned about changing the model, because the application is already in productive use on the server.

Comment: Really you need to investigate this yourself via the shell. Use `car = Tag_car.objects.filter(tag='mytag')[0]` then look at the attributes of `car`, and `car.car`.

Comment: Thank you. In my `Car`-Model I had to add `tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, through='Tag_car')`. Then I was able to access the tags with `car.car.tags.all` within the for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over `car.tag.all` in the template:

```
{% for car in cars %}
    <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ car.car }}">

    <ul>
    {% for tag in car.tag.all %}
        <li>{{ tag }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Also see: [Traversing foreign key related tables in django templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014591/traversing-foreign-key-related-tables-in-django-templates)

Comment: Just tried it. Unfortunately the second for-loop is not being entered at all. Probably because I only pass `Tag_car.objects.filter(tag=search)` from my view and not `Tag_car.objects.all()` !?

Comment: @user2721277 could you try to pass `Tag_car.objects.all()`, just for testing purposes?

Comment: @user2721277 also, please try `car.tag_set.all` instead of `car.tag.all`.

Comment: also when i'm passing `Tag_car.objects.all()` the for-loop is not being entered, neither by using `car.tag_set.all`